# Accessing CollectionViewCell attributes outside of cellForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: swift

Practice, and practice,

Hi there, currently trying to color a `CollectionView Item` once the user tapped my Button.. here i used this code to do

```
 let indexPath2 = NSIndexPath(row:  selected1, section: 1) // selected1 is an Int (0)
 let cell2 = self.MyCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath2 as IndexPath)
 cell2?.contentView.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 39/255, green: 174/255, blue: 96/255, alpha: 1.0) // RED
```

but it won't work. does anyone has any better ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not related to your question but you should drop the NS in Swift3 or later. Just use IndexPath and no need to cast it to IndexPath later.

```
let indexPath2 = IndexPath(row: selected1, section: 1)
```

Don't forget to reload your collection view after changing the cell content. Btw it is Swift convention to name your variables starting with a lowercase letter.

```
MyCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath2])
```